# Unfounded accusations

Tags: discussion

I have been charged with some unjustified accusations and I'm not sure how to deal with it. A user wrote in his comment

"Meanwhile, the fact that you didn't even look at things people found in searches until being asked three     times, and still haven't even tried your own search, doesn't exactly motivate people to try to answer you."

[How to determine if a date was a public holiday in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648520/how-to-determine-if-a-date-was-a-public-holidays-in-python)

This is of course incorrect as I have thoroughly checked the suggestions made in the comments and even asked the local IT to install some of the suggested packages. I have made a search myself even before I posted the question. I don't know what scraping a website is, so I asked for additional explanations. But instead of getting help I now have to deal with unfounded accusation. I flagged the comment as offensive.

The other issue is that I believe my question is not off-topic after my latest edits, but now I don't think it will be judged fairly.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Really, you beat me to it. The Meta EXP helps, too.

Comment: Bad form naming user by name. Makes your defense much weaker.

Comment: @Bit it's not like the other user's name is exactly a secret.

Comment: I've removed the offending user's name from the question.

Comment: @Pëkka, it's not about keeping the user confidential, it's about directing focus. Naming a specific user makes it sound like it's about that user, or that it's a vendetta post (especially if you repeat the name several times). The idea is to explicitly omit the person's name to focus on the actual issue. I think this post would have received a lot fewer down votes if the tone had just been a little different from the start.

Answer (score 23):

I agree the interaction on that post was kinda abrasive. SO has a growing reputation for being full of rude people and sadly that is often true.

The other user also mistook your question about web scraping as laziness. Try to forgive him that one, though, as that question gets asked literally a dozen times a day by lazy newbee users.  That was just an unfortunate misunderstanding.

I'm not sure I'd support reopening your question, though. Here's why:

- Resource requests are a slippery slope on Stack Overflow - most of them are off topic. Yours is kind of  a borderline case but ultimately you are asking for a library, which we no longer do here.
- Your request *looks* specific, but actually is super broad, almost offensively so. Every country has their own complex system of holidays. Hence, the sentence `a certain locality such as New York, London, Tokyo, Sydney` contains entire *universes* of local, specific rules, issues, data sets, specialties and perhaps even entire libraries. Asking for something this broad on SO is also a slippery slope.
- Always make sure you do prior research and make sure you mention it. For example, a Google query for `How to determine if a date was a public holidays in python?`  turns up several Stack Overflow and other resources. How did they not work for you? Why?

Comment: I appreciate your points. I just want to point out that my question is not as broad as you imply. I'm only asking for the holidays that have already happened. You don't need to know any rules for that, just a list of some past dates (going back to, say, 1970, and updated yearly). In principle, it could be part of the datetime class. I was hoping for something like that when I asked my question.

Comment: @Andrey fair enough, but's arguably still a resource request. I'm sure the data exists out there though, perhaps not in a Python library but as a data set. The issue is pretty complex though, just check out public holidays in the US and look at the insane state-by-state table http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_the_United_States other countries have similar regional obscurities

Comment: @AndreySokolov: Then your question is absolutely off-topic. You're asking us to recommend or find an off-site resource or library (a database of past holidays), and that is clearly off topic according to the [SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Ken White I am asking how to address a specific problem in python.

Comment: @Andrey you can pose *any* resource request in a way that makes it look like a specific problem in language xyz. But if you're honest, it's a request for an off-site resource.

Comment: @Andrey: No, you're not. A direct quote from your first comment to this answer: "**You don't need to know any rules for that, just a list of some past dates (going back to, say, 1970, and updated yearly).**". That's a request for data, not a programming solution in Python or any other language, which is clearly indicated with the part you enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: @Ken White You are quoting my comment here, not the question itself. In any case, asking the question was useful to me as I got some interesting suggestions on how to go about addressing this problem. Others may find it useful and even offer a solution. My point is that I don't see any harm from leaving my question open.

Comment: @Andrey off-topic questions are closed on Stack Overflow because their continued existence would serve as justification for yet more off-topic questions. The fact that some people may find it useful is not a good argument here.

Comment: @AndreySokolov: From your question itself: " I am only concerned with past dates (going back to 2002)", which clearly asks for data, and the answer you got consists of nothing but two links to external sites (which is also inappropriate at SO). I'm finished here; you're clearly not listening to what we're saying, so there's no point in wasting more time trying to explain.

Comment: @Ken White I get your points, but I leave it to the community to decide if it is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 12):

If you've made some effort before asking, you should *mention that fact in your question*. If you don't, how are we to know that you've done so? We can't see your screen, read your browser history (or your mind). How do we tell the difference between your question and the ones that ask "I want to do something, and don't want to do the work myself. Someone write the code for me"?

If you've done searches elsewhere, describe those searches. If you've made an effort to write code, mention it (and when possible include the code you've attempted, and explain how it didn't work or didn't solve the problem).

I don't see any indication in your question that you've made any effort to solve the problem prior to posting the question at SO. You should edit the question to mention it, to avoid the appearance that you've failed to do so.

(As a general rule, you should also avoid naming particular users when there's an issue, and simply reference the question specifically and comments in general, rather than singling out a specific individual. If one individual user's comments appear to be overly rude or offensive, you can flag that comment directly for a moderator to review. I didn't see anything worthy of a flag when I looked through the comments, though.)

Comment: I agree that showing your previous work is relevant and useful, but is it a requirement on this site to show your work when posting a question? I don't think so, especially if the question is simple (or perceived to be simple by the user).

Comment: It's not required, but if you don't mention it, you clearly can't object when people think you haven't done it. :-) One of the [standard close reasons for off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - see the section with the numbered list - is "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**" (**emphasis mine**).

Comment: At StackOverflow, we downvote or vote to close. It's your responsibility to provide the information in your question, not ours to pry it from you. *You* are asking *us* for help, not the other way around. You need to write the question in a way that clearly indicates what you've done, what you've tried, how you expect it to work, and in what way it doesn't. We need to enforce that, because if we didn't the site would be flooded with thousands of questions that have no value for future readers. SO isn't for solving your immediate issue; it's for building a knowledge base for others as well.